# C++ String output from MySQL connector with graphics interface either crashes or prints garbage

Tags: string, mysql-connector, ostream

THE PROBLEM:

I have the my sql query running correctly when the output is console, but I get ^^^!^^^^^! on the graphics interface or it crashes.

My program is compiled on Visual Studio 2005 and I use Allegro.cc library This is a old project that must be revived.

What I want to do is:

1- Run a graphics interface, have some action going, them save the data on MySQL.

2- Every now and them, I need to query the DB and get some data.

3- I want to display the data queried onto the graphics screen.

MySQl Connector is 1.1.7 with binaries from site.

MySQL is running on XAMP Turnkey Linux box 5.5.33-0+wheezy1

The Schema engine is: InnoDB
The table collation is utf-8 default collation
The PK is NN, AI.

One column name is PointOfSaleID, VARCHAR (9)
Another column name is cardIndex, INT(11)

The piece of code is below:

```
std::stringstream OutputStream;
(...)

prep_stmt = con -> prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM `Triangulo`.`CardsSold` WHERE HitsA > 4 AND HitsB > 4 AND HitsC >4");

res = prep_stmt -> executeQuery();

con -> commit();

while (res -> next()) {
    OutputStream << res -> getInt("idCardsSold");
    textprintf_ex(OUTPUT, font, 10, 10, makecol(255,255,255), 

makecol(0,0,0), "Winner Card %s", OutputStream.str().c_str() );
        OutputStream.str(std::string()); // clear the string stream

CRASHES HERE!    OutputStream << res -> getString("PointOfSaleID");
        textprintf_ex(OUTPUT, font, 10, 300, makecol(255,255,255), makecol(0,0,0), "PointOfSaleID %s", OutputStream.str().c_str() );
```

When I do the same thing on the console - text output - the program runs correctly.

```
    prep_stmt = con -> prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM `Triangulo`.`CardsSold` WHERE HitsA > 4 AND HitsB > 3 AND HitsC >4");

res = prep_stmt -> executeQuery();

con -> commit();

    /* fetch the data : retrieve all the rows in the result set */

while (res -> next()) {
    cout << Card: ";
    cout << res -> getInt("idCardsSold") << endl;


    OutputStream << res -> getString("PointOfSaleID");
    std::string resultstr = OutputStream.str();

    const char* cstr2 = resultstr.c_str();

    cout << "Loja Venda: ";
    cout << cstr2 << endl;

    cout << res -> getString("PointOfSaleID") << endl;
}
```

It seems to be a problem with the std::stringstream OutputStream, but I can not find out what is going on.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error was mine. I used the wrong library settings and combinations in Visual Studio. For those who would like to know, it was a mish mash of libraries from MySQL Connector for cpp with the other libraries from MySQL server. I re-read the instructions and found that there were mistakes.
The catch is that the connector worked for getInt() even with the wrong library settings, elements and combinations and did not work for getString().

The method I used maybe of importance to newbies like me, thus it is listed below:

1- Reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the error.
2- Read the documentation of the products you want to use.
3- Try to explain to others, in writing and verbose form, how you want to accomplish what.
4- Revise your own question after some sleep.

This worked for me.